# Not able to click on Label in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click on label, but not able to. Here is my code:

```
 function nameToggle(){              
                 var NameInput = get("nameInput");  
                 var labelName = nameInput.getLabel();
                 alert(labelName);
                 labelName.onclick = showAlert;                         
            } 
             function showAlert(){
                 alert("onclick Event Detected");
             }
```

And here is my html:

```
<div id="nameShow">
    <div  style="margin: 36px 0 0 50px;">
            <input id="nameInput"  label="Name"  onkeydown="namesFunction()"/>                  

    </div>
</div>
```

In the input I want to onkeydown call namesfunction which works perfectly but when click on label(Name) I want to toggle. I am calling nameToggle in another function. But I am not able to click on "Name". i am not using jQuery. only Javascript. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Label is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: correction: var NameInput = document.getElementById("nameInput"); and label is a custom attribute.

Comment: What is `getLabel()` ?

Comment: getLabel get the label value like in this case "Name".

Answer (score 0):

1) Inside your function `nameToggle()`you have assigned onclick to `labelName`, but thats a string ("Name"). Assign onclick to `NameInput` which is the element:

```
function nameToggle(){
    var NameInput = document.getElementById("nameInput");
    var labelName = nameInput.getLabel();
    alert(labelName);
    NameInput.onclick = showAlert; // <---                    
}
```

2) Since you make the onclick-assignment inside the function, you have to invoke it somewhere with `nameToggle()` **before** you can click.

If you don't want that you have to make the assignment **outside** a function:

```
document.getElementById("nameInput").onclick = showAlert;
```

**Edit** According to your comment: Only a DOM-element is clickable. Your `label` is only an attribute of an element and you can't click an attribute. Make the label a real element in your html just before the input like so:

```
<label for="nameInput" onclick="showAlert()">Name</label>
```

The `for`-attribute says that this `<label>` belongs to input with id = nameInput. You can assign the onclick inside the tag as shown above or with:

```
 document.querySelector("label[for='nameInput']").onclick = showAlert;
```

Comment: when I change to NameInput.onclick, the showAlert function is invoked when I click the input box. I want to click the label "Name".